# TFS 2013 | Test Step Detail tab invisible in Test Result

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I created a test case, added few test steps, and now, am populating test step results in Test Step Details tab after a test is run. 
I am able to see the test step details tab with each test case details like description, expected result, passes/failed etc. But only if, it is a manual test case. 
This tab doesn't appear for automated test case.

I referred to below link for achieving this - 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aseemb/2012/08/06/code-snippets-on-test-management-apis/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test case steps are designed for [manual test](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/manual-exploratory-testing/getting-started/create-test-cases). In manual test, you need to run test according to steps and set the result manually.

But for automatic tests, it doesn't need to run test step by step, it runs automatically and the result is generated automatically. So there no step concept in automatic tests because your test method are the "steps" for this test case. That's why you can't see the test step results details in MTM.

Comment: Is there anyway to populate the step details for automated test case somehow ? I have such requirement.

Comment: @Stark Unfortunately, it doesn't support currently. Because in auto tests, those steps won't be run. Maybe you could submit a user voice [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services?query=automatic%20test%20case%20step). Microsoft TFS product team is listening to User Voice there.